# Creating 1D arrays of mpfr_t types in C

Tags: arrays, c, mpfr

I am working with the *GNU MPFR* library, I write some simple *C* code.
I am trying to create a one-elemental array of `mpfr_t` objects:

```c
mpfr_t result;
// (some code that assigned values to the variable 'result')
mpfr_t temparr[1];
temparr[0] = result;
mpfr_clear(result);
```

And I get the following error:

> ./library/file.hpp:663:20: error: array type 'mpfr_t' (aka '__mpfr_struct [1]') is not assignable
> 1 error generated.
> Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

What should I modify here? Also - I guess I have to additionally clear the `temparr[0]` variable too, right?

---

Since I am here, I might as well ask about dynamical arrays. Later in the code, in another function, I have:

```c
mpfr_t* temparr = new mpfr_t[var];
// some code
for (unsigned int i=0; i < var; i++) mpfr_clear(temparr[i]);
delete[] temparr;
```

I guess this is alright, no? It is not raising any errors during compilation now, at least...

Comment: [Section 5.2](https://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/mpfr.html#Assignment-Functions) is where you can find the assignment functions. You'll also want to see the initialization functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the MPFR manual:

> The C data type for such objects is ‘mpfr_t’, internally defined as a one-element array of a structure

This explains that you cannot do assignments of `mpfr_t` directly.

Moreover, the `mpfr_t` array does not contain all the data that define the MPFR number (this is something more or less missing in the manual; this is described in the [*Internals*](https://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/mpfr.html#Internals) section, but I suppose that users should not have to read this section to warn them against doing incorrect things). This means that, in general, you are not allowed to just copy the `mpfr_t` array (e.g. by `memcpy`). The only safe way to copy MPFR numbers is via the MPFR interface, e.g. `mpfr_set`.

Your C++ code seems correct (at least the part you wrote). You may define arrays of `mpfr_t`.